# how to concatenate a string and a variable and assign a value in it in python

Tags: python-3.x

Is there anyway to assign value in concatenated variable?

I want to `concatenate` and assign a value in it.

```
for i in range (5):
    'serial_' + str(i) = i+5
```

that showing `SyntaxError: can't assign to operator`

Comment: This looks like a perfect use for a dictionary.

Comment: possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1373164/how-do-i-create-a-variable-number-of-variables

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is possible to add variables with concatenated names in the global/local symbol table using the [`globals`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#globals) and [`locals`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#locals) built-in functions:

```
>>> for i in range (5):
...     global()['serial_' + str(i)] = i+5
... 
>>> serial_0
5
>>> serial_3
8
```

However according to the documentation, changing the dictionary returned by `locals` may have no effect to the values of local variables used by the interpreter.

Furthermore since modifying the global symbol table is not considered a good practice, I recommend you to use a dictionary to store your values as suggested by [Mayank Porwal](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5820814/mayank-porwal) as this will result in cleaner code:

```
>>> d = {f'serial_{i}' : i + 5 for i in range(5)}
>>> d
{'serial_0': 5, 'serial_1': 6, 'serial_2': 7, 'serial_3': 8, 'serial_4': 9}
```

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly,

```
d = {}
In [898]: for i in range (5):
     ...:    d[ ('{}' + str(i)).format('serial_')] = i+5


In [899]: d
Out[899]: {'serial_0': 5, 'serial_1': 6, 'serial_2': 7, 'serial_3': 8, 'serial_4': 9}
```

Let me know if this is what you want.

Comment: It is only concatenation. i want to use this(serial_5,serial_6...) as variable name.

Comment: well this will work but i also want to know is there other way to do this without dict. like a simple variable (serial_0 =5)